# Using mat-error and valueAccessor is not working inside mat-form-field

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-reactive-forms, angular-components

I'm looking to create some reusable form components

Template

```
  <mat-form-field appearance="outline">
    <mat-label>Postalcode</mat-label>
    <input
      matInput
      [value]="value"
      (input)="onChanged($event.target.value)"
      (blur)="onTouched()"
    />
    <mat-error>
      {{ errorsTranslations.required | translate }}
    </mat-error>
  </mat-form-field>


@Component({
  selector: 'ssp-postal-code',
  templateUrl: './postal-code.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./postal-code.component.scss'],
  changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush,
  providers: [
    { provide: MatFormFieldControl, useExisting: PostalCodeComponent }
  ]
})
export class PostalCodeComponent implements ControlValueAccessor {

  @Input() ctrl: FormControl;
  value: string;

  public onTouched: () => void;
  public onChanged: () => void;

  get errorsTranslations() {
    return this._translation.keys.validatonsErrors;
  }

  constructor(
    private readonly _translation: TranslationService<Translations>,
    @Optional() @Self() public ngControl: NgControl,
  ) {
    if (this.ngControl != null) {
      // Setting the value accessor directly (instead of using the providers) to avoid running into a circular import.
      this.ngControl.valueAccessor = this;
    }
  }

  writeValue(value: string): void {
    this.value = value ? value : '';
  }

  registerOnChange(fn: any): void {
    this.onChanged = fn;
  }

  registerOnTouched(fn: any): void {
    this.onTouched = fn;
  }

  setDisabledState?(isDisabled: boolean): void {
    throw new Error('Method not implemented.');
  }
```

The validations works and the control has all the errors eg. if I place this outside of the mat-form-field it does show.. but not inside... ?

```
    <mat-error *ngIf="ctrl.errors?.required">
      {{ errorsTranslations.required | translate }}
    </mat-error>
```

Comment: How are you setting required validator to custom form control?

Comment: The formgroup is created in the parent component and passed down.. it works and I can see the validation errors in the {{ctrl.errors}} object.. it's just that the material form field is not registering an error :/

Comment: I think since you using cva you don't need to pass the control to child component

Comment: the problem was that I needed to add [formControl]="ngControl".. all is good now :)